# How can I make a Perl hash from an array with the keys and another array with the values?

Tags: perl, arrays, hash

In Perl, how do I make hash from arrays `@A` and `@B` having equal number of elements? The goal is to have each value of `@A` as key to value in `@B`. The resulting hash `%C` would,then make it possible to uniquely identify an element from `@B` supplying key from `@A`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

it's as simple as

```
my %c;
@c{@a} = @b;
```

Comment: Great! I forgot about the slice solution, though I use it regularly.

Comment: You're probably reading the wrong books. _Learning Perl_ shows this in the slice section. :)

Answer (score 8):

```
use List::MoreUtils 'mesh';
my %c = mesh @a, @b;
```

That's how it's made internally (if you're sure about equal number of elements):

```
my %c = map { $a[$_] => $b[$_] } 0 .. $#a;
```

Comment: Nice one, I hadn't thought about using map.

Comment: or roll your own: `sub mesh { @_[map $_&1 ? $_>>1 : ($_>>1)+($#_>>1), 1..@_] }`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem correctly:

```
my %c;
$c{$a[$_]} = $b[$_] for (0 .. @a-1);
```

Comment: I really like Perl, but sometimes one can despair on a programming language allowing you for more non-letter chars than letters in your source code...

Comment: @Boldewyn: usually fixed by using real variable names

Answer (score 0):

A's are the keys, B's are the values of hash C:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a = 1 .. 3;
my @b = 4 .. 6;
my %c;
for (0 .. $#a) {
    $c{$a[$_]} = $b[$_]
}
```

Keep in mind that there must not be any duplicate values in the A array.